# Python - Format a string from a list not working

Tags: python, xpath

I want to crawl a webpage for some information and what I've done so far It's working but I need to do a request to another url from the website, I'm trying to format it but it's not working, this is what I have so far:

```
name = input("> ")

page = requests.get("http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champions")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

for index, champ in enumerate(champ_list):
    if name == champ:
        y = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='browse-build']/a[{}]/@href".format(index + 1))
        print(y)

        guide = requests.get("http://www.mobafire.com{}".format(y))
        builds = html.fromstring(guide.content)
        print(builds)

        for title in builds.xpath(".//table[@class='browse-table']/tr[2]/td[2]/div[1]/a/text()"):
            print(title)
```

From the input, the user enters a name; if the name matches one from a list (`champ_list`) it prints an url and from there it formats it to the `guide` variable and gets another information but I'm getting errors such as `invalid ipv6`.

This is the output url (one of them but they're similar anyway) `['/league-of-legends/champion/ivern-133']`

I tried using slicing but it doesn't do anything, probably I'm using it wrong or it doesn't work in this case. I tried using replace as well, they don't work on lists; tried using it as:

`y = [y.replace("'", "") for y in y]` so I could see if it removed at least the quotes but it didn't work neither; what can be another approach to format this properly?

Comment: I am conpletely at a loss what you're asking. Can you boild down the problem? We don't need your networking code. You are jsut trying to format a string correct?

Comment: @MaxUppenkamp Sorry If I didn't explain myself too clear; the code was just to see what was going on; I want to format the output of `y` into `guide` but it's always throwing me the errors that I listed above; what I'm thinking is that it formats `y` into `guide` wrongly; something like: `http://www.mobafire.com['/league-of-legends/champion/ivern-133']` and obviously that's wrong; I want to remove `[, ] and '` from the output of `y`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it y is the list you want to insert into the string?

Try this:

```
"http://www.mobafire.com{}".format('/'.join(y))
```

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for, thank you! Give me some minutes to accept your answer :)